# Linear Algebra - Given the Jordan form of $A \in Mat_7(\mathbb F)$, find Jordan form of $A^2+A+I_7$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, jordan-normal-form

Given that the jordan form of the matrix $A \in Mat_7(\mathbb F)$ is:

$\begin{pmatrix} J_2(1) &\cdots &0\\0& \cdots J_3(1) \cdots &0\\0&0& \cdots J_2(2)\end{pmatrix}$

Find the Jordan form of $A^2+A+I$

Clarification: $J_{\alpha}(\beta)$ is a jordan block of size $\alpha$ with $\beta$ on the diagonal.

What I did:

I tried bruteforcing it, as in actually calculating $A^2+A+I$, but now to find the minimal polynomial of a 7x7 matrix...not fun. Is there a smarter way to go about this question?

From the jordan form of $A$ I can infer the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of $A$. Does that have any implication on the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A^2+A+I$?

Comment: A tiny hint that may or may not be of specific use to you: $(A^2+A+I)(A-I)=A^3-I$...

Comment: I wonder if that's applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $$ A = SJS^{-1} $$
then

$$A^2+A+I = \left(SJS^{-1}\right)^2+\left(SJS^{-1}\right)+SS^{-1} = S\left(J^2+J+I\right)S^{-1}$$

Comment: Brilliant!!!!...But that doesn't help that much. Now I need to find the Jordan form of $J^2+J+I$, thats still a 7 by 7 matrix

Comment: $(J^2+J+I)$  has the same amount of "blocks" as $J$ and you only have to handle each of those blocks independently. Those blocks are either Jordan blocks, or triangular and easy to get into JNF

Comment: So I don't need to actually find the Jordan form of $J^2+J+I$? I can find the jordan form of each block individually and infer from that the jordan form of the matrix im looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

We have $C_{A}(x) = (x-1)^{5}(x-2)^{2}$ and $m_{A}(x) = (x-1)^{3}(x-2)^{2}$. 
Write $B = A^{2} + A + I$. Then $Av = \lambda v \implies Bv = (\lambda^{2} + \lambda + 1)v$.
This equation tells us what the eigenvalues of $B$ look like, but also more:  $ \ker(A-\lambda I) \subset \ker \left (B - (\lambda^{2} + \lambda + 1)I\right)$ and the reverse inclusion also holds. Therefore, the structure of $J_{A}$ is preserved. Thus, $C_{B}(x) = (x-3)^{5}(x-7)^{2}$ and $m_{B}(x) = (x-3)^{3}(x-7)^{2}$.